# Finding value of previous sibling for dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a simple jQuery shopping list as my first jQuery project.  I'm adding each item dynamically, and allowing the user to pass in a price for estimated cost.  I'm displaying the total estimated cost as each item is added to the list.

In the event the user wants to delete an item I would like to remove the item and update the total cost. This is my code for adding the item with cost...

```
 //Append individual ITEM and individual PRICE to document
    var addToList = '<li class="addedItem">' +addItem+ 
    '<span> will cost you $</span>' +addPrice+ 
    '<button class="delete">Delete</button></li>';
    $('#items').append(addToList);
```

How can I select onlythe added price of the item being deleted so that the total can be subtracted from accordingly?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //Stop the form from submitting
  $('#submit-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });

  //Variables to store totals
  var itemCounter = 0;
  var priceCounter = 0;

  //Handler to get value of ITEM and PRICE
  $('#submit-btn').click(function() {

    //Get value for submitted item and append to list
    var addItem = $('#item').val();
    itemCounter++;

    //Functionality to keep track of TOTAL PRICE and be able to remove an 
    //item so the price reflects the removal
    var addPrice = Number.parseInt($('#cost').val());
    alert(typeof(addPrice));
    priceCounter += addPrice;





    //Append ITEM and PRICE to document
    var addToList = '<li class="addedItem">' + addItem + '<span> will cost you $</span>' + addPrice + '<button class="delete">Delete</button></li>';
    $('#items').append(addToList);

    //Clear the form after submit
    $('#item').val('');
    $('#cost').val('');

    //Clear ESTIMATED COST TOTAL and append new total
    $('#estimatedCost').html('');
    $('#estimatedCost').append(priceCounter);


    //Appends totals to TOTALS
    //HTML to append
    $('#itemsTotal').html('');
    $('#itemsTotal').append(itemCounter);


  });

  //Functionality for Delete Button
  $(document).on('click', '.delete', function() { //Because the delete button has been created   
                                                  //dynamically you must specify    
    $(this).parent().remove();                     //to listen to the DOCUMENT for the click on 'DELETE'
    $(this).remove();
    alert($(this).prev().val());
    $('#estimatedCost').append(priceCounter);


  });

  //Function to create sum all off prices
  function sumPrice() {}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Let's Go Shopping!</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css'>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src='js/script.js'></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <header>
            <h4>A handy app to keep your spending on track!</h4>
        </header>
        
        <div class='main-form'>
            <form id='submit-form' name='submit-form'>
                    <!--        Form submit for ITEM        -->
                <input type='text' id='item' placeholder="What Should I Get?">
                <input type='number' value='number' id='cost' placeholder="Estimated Cost"><br>
                <input type='submit' name='submit-btn' id='submit-btn' value="Let's get it!">           
            </form>
        </div>
        
        <section id='list'>
        <ul id='items'></ul>
            <div id='totals'>
                <div><h3>Items to Buy</h3></div>
                <div id='itemsTotal'></div>
            </div>
            <div><h3>Esitmated Cost</h3></div>
            <div id='estimatedCost'></div>
        </section>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest is add it to the button as a data attribute

```
var addToList = '<li class="addedItem">' +addItem+ 
    '<span> will cost you $</span>' +addPrice+ 
    '<button class="delete" data-price="'+addPrice +'">Delete</button></li>'
```

Then in click handler

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete', function() {

  var price = +$(this).data('price');
  // do price calcs


   // other code left out
});
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  Out of curiosity, what does the + do in...
    var price = +$(this).data('price');

Comment: coerces string value to number. jQuery data() should do it automatically but i think that is changing in 3.0

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just change the order of the lines?

```
// first of all, while it's not removed yet:
var price = parseFloat($(this).prev().text());
alert(price);
$(this).parent().remove();
$(this).remove();
```

Comment: `prev()` is a `<span>` with text in it